# How do I follow a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, stack-exchange

I would like to follow a recent question I've read on Stack Overflow which currently doesn't have an answer.
Is that possible? With current grades I can't even vote it up.
Thank you!

Comment: you're right, sorry! when I hover over the star i get a label that says "add this question to your favourites", which is slightly different from "follow this question", AFAIK ;) thanks